# In the example here, why would one differentiate with respect to x and not to y?

Tags: calculus

"Differentiate the expression $x^{2}y^{3}$ with respect to $x$. (Use $D$ for $\frac{dy}{dx}$)."

In the above question, is there a particular reason why would one differentiate with respect to $x$ and not to $y$? Or can you do both, but differentiating with $x$ is easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $x^2$ is a function of $x$.
To differentiate $y^3$ with respect to $x$ , you should be given that $y$ is differentiable with respect to $x$.

If so , let $E=x^2y^3$

Then $\frac{dE}{dx}=x^2\cdot3y^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}+y^3\cdot2x$

If you want its' derivative with respect to $y$,

$\frac{dE}{dy}=x^2\cdot3y^2+y^3\cdot2x\cdot\frac{dx}{dy}$

If you want its' derivative with respect to $t$

$\frac{dE}{dt}=x^2\cdot3y^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}+y^3\cdot2x\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$